# Predicate Push Down vs Bloom Filters

Tags: bigdata, orc

While looking for Query optimizations on Big data especially an ORC file  , I I came across two possibilities predicate push down and Bloom Filters .

Predicate push down helps us to avoid reading unnecessary stripes, which helps to reduce IO , but to me it appears that Bloom Filter also serves the same purpose except the below.

for predicate push down we do not need to explicitly create any artifacts while writing an ORC file , where as for Bloom filters we need to configure the columns for while writing to ORC file.

Request suggestions to get my understanding better.

Thanks
Santosh

Answer (score 1):

Bloom filters are used by predicate push down. Predicate push down uses column statistics primarily to skip row groups and minimize number of rows read. If bloom filters are used then predicate push down can minimize number of rows read further.

Comment: Hi Ajay ,

    Thank you for the responding to my question ,  if I understand it correctly in absence of Bloom Filters Predicate pushdown works based on Indexes created per stripe such as Min,Max values stored at stripe level. when Bloom Filters are created Predicate push down takes help from Bloom Filters to reduce data set further.

Thanks

Comment: If the above statement is correct , I have follow-up question based on bloom filter behavior , it seems they only provide the information whether the data point is present in  a set (or) not  this helps to skip the entire stripe , but what I could not understand is  how does it help to reduce the number of rows read from the stripe.

Comment: @VaradaSantosh Examining Min,Max of a stripe gives an indication that a column value may be present in the stripe. Bloom filters will help in skipping this stripe if value is not present as bloom filter are 100% correct about absence of value. But bloom filters can report false positives so the scanning of stripe becomes necessary in that case. So, bloom filters help in skipping stripe when value is not present in stripe and that reduces number of rows read. It's not that it reduces number of rows read within a stripe.

Comment: Rows read using (Min,Max) and bloomfilter <= Rows read using (Min, Max)
and it happens only by skipping stripes or row-groups.

Answer (score 0):

Because ORC files are type-aware, the writer chooses the most appropriate encoding for the type and builds an internal index as the file is written.

Predicate push down uses those indexes to determine which stripes in a file need to be read for a particular query and the row indexes can narrow the search to a particular set of 10,000 rows

seealso: https://orc.apache.org/docs/index.html

- Predicate push down needs to implemented by the query engine like apache spark

A good definition about predicate push down can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54708991/how-does-predicate-pushdown-work-exactly) and:

[https://medium.com/microsoftazure/data-at-scale-learn-how-predicate-pushdown-will-save-you-money-7063b80878d7#:~:text=What%20is%20Predicate%20Pushdown%3F,are%20referred%20to%20as%20predicates.&text=It%20can%20improve%20query%20performance,%2FO](https://medium.com/microsoftazure/data-at-scale-learn-how-predicate-pushdown-will-save-you-money-7063b80878d7#:%7E:text=What%20is%20Predicate%20Pushdown%3F,are%20referred%20to%20as%20predicates.&text=It%20can%20improve%20query%20performance,%2FO))%20from%20Storage%20files

ORC provides three level of indexes within each file:

1. file level - statistics about the values in each column across the entire file
2. stripe level - statistics about the values in each column for each stripe
3. row level - statistics about the values in each column for each set of 10,000 rows within a stripe

Column statistics always contain the count of values and whether there are null values present. Most other primitive types include the minimum and maximum values and for numeric types the sum. **As of Hive 1.2, the indexes can include bloom filters, which provide a much more selective filter**.

https://orc.apache.org/docs/indexes.html

**ORC predicate push-down is enabled by default in Spark SQL.**

[Bloom filters are only useful for equality, not less than or greater than.](https://www.slideshare.net/oom65/orc-deep-dive-2020)

"A Bloom filter is a space-efficient probabilistic data structure, conceived by Burton Howard Bloom in 1970, that **is used to test whether an element is a member of a set**. False positive matches are possible, but false negatives are not – in other words, **a query returns either "possibly in set" or "definitely not in set"**."

Seealso:

https://llimllib.github.io/bloomfilter-tutorial/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter

https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.2.8/developing-spark-applications/topics/spark-predicate-push-down-optimization.html