# How does predicate pushdown work exactly?

Tags: hadoop, parquet, orc

Could anyone please explain with examples how exactly predicate pushdown works?

Comment: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_predicate_pushdown_parquet.html

Comment: @cricket_007 well, when I was googling it, those cloudera links did not pop up for me at all. I am pretty sure next time someone googles this, the first link that will pop up will be this one.

Comment: I was just moving that from the now deleted answer. But still, you should at least show what you did search for, if anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say you want to execute a query

```
SELECT 
  SUM(price) 
FROM sales 
WHERE 
  purchase_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-31';
```

A very trivial implementation of a query engine is to iterate over all parquet/orc files, deserialize the `price` and `purchase_date` columns, apply the predicate on the `purchase_date` and sum the filtered rows.

Parquet (not sure about orc) maintains statistics on the columns in each file, so if the execution engine is smart enough, it can look at the min/max of the `purchase_date` within the statistics and determine if any rows is going to match. For example, if `purchase_date.min=2014-05-05` and `purchase_date.max=2014-05-06`, it can deduce that the predicate will always evaluate to false.

In other words, it can skip parquet files by combining statistics and the filter predicate . This can lead to massive gain of performance because IO (file or memory) is usually the bottleneck. The gain is inversely proportional to the selectivity (the percentage of matching rows).

The term predicate push-down comes from the fact that you're "hinting" the scan operator with the predicate that is then going to be used to filter the rows of interest. Or, pushing the predicate to the scan.